# how to passing parameter 3d no global variable

Tags: c++

Is the way the pass a 3D array as a parameter no global variable to function C++ ?
I want to input the size after run

```
int partition(int *a[size][size],int l,int r )
{
    int pivot=l;
    while(l<r)
    {
        while(a[pivot][0][0]>=a[l][0][0]) { l++;}
        while(a[pivot][0][0]<a[r][0][0]){r++;}
        if(l<r){std::swap(a[l][0][0],a[r][0][0];)}
    }
    std::swap(a[pivot][0][0],a[r][0][0]);
    return r;
}
void quick_sort(int *a,int l,int r)
{
    if(l<r)
    {
        int pivot=partition(a,l,r);
        quick_sort(a,l,pivot-1);
        quick_sort(a,pivot+1,r);
    }
}
int main()
{
  int size;
  std::cin>>size;
  int a[size][size][size];
  quick_sort(a,l,size-1);
}
```

I want to sort 3d array only X variable ("a[x][0][0]") but I find the answer.I found only set const.I can't do this.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: `std::cin>>size; int a[size][size][size];` is invalid C++, it use non portable VLA **extension**.

Comment: What should i do @Jarod42

Comment: As molbdnilo said, use `std::vector`. (or library with matrix classes).

Comment: Can you write the code? @Jarod42

Comment: It seems you only sort one "row", so quicksort/partition should only take 1D-array (pointer or iterator or `std::vector`).

Comment: I mean ```std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > >  player(  n, std::vector<int>  (n,vector<int> (n,0))  ); ``` I don't sure declear like this ? for ```a[n][n][n]``` @Jarod42

Comment: You might try yourself, ask another question if you have issue. but declaration seems fine to me.